# How do I pass objects between `HandleAuthenticateAsync` and `HandleChallengeAsync` in my custom `AuthenticationHandler`?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api

I can't work out the correct way to pass objects from `HandleAuthenticateAsync` , where my custom authentication code is, to the `HandleChallengeAsync` callback, where I handle the authentication failure and set the response status code and body.

If authentication fails, I want to return a JSON object which includes some information in the response body about why authentication failed.

In my handler code, I want to serialize some values from `results` in the `HandleChallengeAsync` method:

```cs
public class ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public const string ApiKeyHeaderName = "X-API-KEY";

    public ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    // The authentication handler that gets call for every request (including `[AllowAnonymous]`
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        Request.Headers.TryGetValue(Options.ApiKeyHeaderName, out var apiKeyHeaderValues);
        var key = apiKeyHeaderValues.FirstOrDefault();

        var results = await new AuthenticateApiKeyQuery(key).Results();

        if (results.HasErrors())
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Useless message that doesn't go anywhere");

        return Success(results.Value);
    }

    // the callback that gets called for any `[Authorize]` actions
    override protected async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        var errors = new { }; // I want `errors` to come from the `result` object above
        Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errors);
        await Context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
    }

    // Method that sent up the identity/claim etc
    private AuthenticateResult Success(ApiKey apiKey)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, apiKey.ID.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, apiKey.Description),
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Options.AuthenticationType);
        var identities = new List<ClaimsIdentity> { identity };
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identities);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Options.AuthenticationScheme);

        return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
    }
```

My initial attempt had the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method set the 401 and response body.  This does not work as the authentication handler is also run for actions tagged with `[AllowAnonymous]`.  The result is that the response will be 401, and the serialized JSON, rather than the status and response set by the action.  Whereas, `HandleChallengeAsync`, is only called when authentication fails and the action requires authorization.

This isn't the easiest of code to navigate, but from what I can tell, `PolicyEvalulator` calls `AuthenticationHandler` which then calls my custom `HandleAuthenticateAsync`.  The `AuthenticateResult` I return then gets swallowed up by the `PolicyEvalulator`, so I cant use it to hold any values for later processing.  I haven't yet worked out what calls my custom `HandleChallengeAsync`, but by this point the `AuthenticateResult` has been swallowed up.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issues, The authentication handler is transient-scoped, you can declare a object type property in your Custom Handler class and that will be available in HandleChallengeAsync method.